# Surjectivity of some evaluation map on global sections of a positive vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective manifold, let $E \rightarrow X$ be a Hermitian vector bundle and let $L \rightarrow X$ be a positive Hermitian line bundle. Let $H^0(X,E \otimes L^d)$ denote the space of global holomorphic sections of $E \otimes L^d$. I believe the following fact to be true and I'm looking for a reference.

There exists $d_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $d \geq d_0$, for any tuple $(x_1,\dots,x_p)$ of distinct points in $X^p$, the evaluation map $ev_x : H^0(X,E\otimes L^d) \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^p (E \otimes L^d)_{x_i}$ defined by $ev_x : s \mapsto (s(x_1),\dots,s(x_p))$ is surjective.

Can anyone confirm that this statement is true, and give me a reference for it? Note that I want $d_0$ not to depend on the tuple $(x_1,\dots,x_p)$.

Comment: Do you want "$\exists d_0$ such that $\forall p$", or "$\forall p$ $\exists d_0$"?

Comment: @Sasha I want that $\forall p \ \exists d_0$. The other statement is false since the dimension of the target space grows linearly with $p$.